# How do I programatically determine the time (hours/minutes) and set them to 00/00 in Swift?

Tags: swift, date

I am doing some date math and before doing so am trying to programatically adjust the time associated with a date based on its current value.  In the code below I am able to set the hours and minutes to 00/00 but I have to know the offset and manually set the value.  Below is my code and next to each print statement I have listed the value I am getting.  Any assistance in pointing out the error I am making will be appreciated.  I wonder if it is a timezone issue relative to GMT.

Chris

```
func AdjustDateTime(vooDate: Date) -> Date {
    
    let date = vooDate
    let _ = print("date")
    let _ = print(date)          // returns 2021-10-25 06:00:00 +000
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: date)
    let year = components.year
    let month = components.month
    let day = components.day
    let hour = components.hour
    let minute = components.minute
    
    let _ = print("hour")
    let _ = print(hour!)          // returns 0 even though the date above say 06
    let _ = print("minute")
    let _ = print(minute!)        // returns 0

    var comps = DateComponents()
    comps.year = year
    comps.month = month
    comps.day = day! + 1
    comps.hour = -06              // setting manually, would like to do so programatically
    comps.minute = 00
    
    let returnDate: Date = Calendar.current.date(from: comps)!
    
    let _ = print("Return Date")
    let _ = print(returnDate)     // returns 2021-10-26 00:00:00 +0000, which is what I want
    
    return returnDate
    
}
```

Comment: The hour in your date is not 6:00. it's 6:00 at UTC (i.e. 6 at GMT 0). You (or your phone) must be in central time. Central time is at GMT -6. so 6 - 6 = 0

Comment: I thought about that but I am in MST which is 7 at GMT 0.  Another wrinkle is that the date is obtained from a text string in a JSON file with a format yyyy-MM-dd.  A date formatter is used to convert it to a date object.  So, maybe there is an adjustment to the date formatter that is. needed.

Comment: first of all you probably should use `en_US_POSIX` and `TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)` on your formatter when decoding. Otherwise it will give you a date using your device timezone when in reality the date should have used UTC. Though not all devs are cut from the same cloth so its possible that the date they are sending does not represents UTC but some other timezone, such as where the server is hosted. I've seen this kind of stupidity done many times. One can only hope and assume. Look at the RFC3339DateFormatter here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter.

Comment: Thank you.  FYI the date in the JSON is just text "yyyy-MM-dd".  But it just dawned on me that I am in MST but with daylight savings time we fall back one hour.  I would guess that is why my current date formatter

Comment: Right, totally mountain time is at -6 at at the moment for the next few days anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the time zone as indicated by Jacob was the key to solving the problem.  In the code where I read in the JSON file I modified my  dateFormatter to what's shown below.  This returns a date object as shown below the code.  Now I do not need to worry about the hours, since they are 0.  From there it is easy to add 1 day with a function, shown below.  Before doing my date math I make the same adjustments to a date in the future, i.e. timezone and locale, and I get the correct difference between the two dates which was the ultimate goal.  Thank you for the assistance.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") // added
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)     // added

2021-10-25 00:00:00 +0000


func AdjustDateTime(vooDate: Date) -> Date {
    
  return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: vooDate)!
}
```